# encryption algorithm block cipher and stream cipher

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, stream-cipher

what is differance between stream cipher and block cipher?As in block cipher data are in chucks while in stream cipher bit by bit encrypting so how many data are as input in stream cipher?

Comment: You can find the answer in Wikipedia, for example.

Comment: Both have the same input (depending on mode), it's the output that is different.

Answer (score 1):

The stream in [Stream Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) refers to the key, not the data. In a block cipher, the key encrypts a block of data (typically 8 or 16 bytes) at a time, and normally a [Cipher Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) is used to modify the key from block to block. In a stream cipher, some mechanism is used to generate a key stream and the data is then typically only XOR-ed with the key stream. The key stream can be a [one-time-pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) known beforehand to sender and recipient, or the output of a random number generator with an initial state known to sender and recipient. Even most block ciphers can be used in CTR or OFB mode so they effectively become stream ciphers.

Why would one use a stream cipher? Well, the final operation is a simple XOR, which is very fast. The keystream can be computed independently, even beforehand. Therefore, stream ciphers are popular where encryption in real-time is needed, for example for encrypted telephony.

Why would one not use a stream cipher? Well, the final operation is a simple XOR, which means that regular patterns in the key stream can be exploited by an attacker. Care must be taken to make sure the keystream will never repeat, by using [numbers used once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) and other mechanisms to guarantee uniqueness. With block ciphers, this condition is not as important: while in CBC mode, a random Initialization Vector is preferred, constant IVs are not nearly as dangerous as they are in stream ciphers.

Comment: suppose one page of plain text is there then AES block cipher will divide chucks of data as 128-bit while in stream cipher at a time how many data will it take?As more than one page plain text is there then compare to one page at a time how many data of plain text will it take?